# White spaces send in my file when downloading

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am using the download file function in laravel like so:

```
if(Input::get('download')){
   return Response::download('File_and_path');
}
```

Now this will download the file when I press the button called: `download`. However when I try to open the file(e.g a docx document), it will tell me the file is corrupted and asks me if I would like to repair the file. When I click yes, I get the right file opened. With JPG files I cant repair it like that. It'll just say the file is damaged. When I open the files(which are stored in the downloads folder) in notepad, I see that there's like a tab or white space at the start. Now my colleague said to try out the function: [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) and the file is not damaged anymore upon downloading. However my colleague said that's not the right solution to the problem I'm having.

Before the download function, I upload the file first. in `public/files/` whenever I open it there, it will open without any problems without the `ob_get_clean()`.

When I `var_dump(ob_get_clean());` I get: `string(1) " "`. I tried to find out where I messed up with the code but I cant seem to figure out what the problem is. In this case, where there's just a random tab in the code of the file, where would the problem be? My code is way too much to actually show so I just need direction in where the problem would be.

**NOTE:**

When I use `var_dump(obs_get_clean());` in a different function of the controller, I get: `string(1) " "` as well. The only thing the 2 functions share is a basic layout view and are both defined in the routes.php of course.

Comment: Do you have any php closings in your files? `?>`. Most of the time those are responsible since after them could be spaces.

Comment: @MatthiasLoibl That's it. I totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any php closings in your files? `?>`. Most of the time those are responsible since after them could be spaces.