# Laravel/Nginx/Ubuntu Response Download injects additional characters and truncates file

Tags: laravel, file, nginx, download, httpresponse

When i return a file from my application through the browser using a response download i am receiving a file with the correct size but exactly 4 blank spaces (ord-20) leading the file and the last 4 characters of the file truncated.

I cant work out if this is from the framework or the web server and it seems to be consistent behaviour across different file types, typically pdf and csv files.

a typical pdf response would look like
`

```
    $pdf->save( storage_path('invoices/'.$filename) );

    return response()->download(
        storage_path('invoices/'.$filename),
        $filename,
        [
            'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
            'Content-Type: application/pdf;',
        ]
    )->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

`
using Snappy/pdf to generate the pdf. testing of the pdf as stored on server shows the file as saved before transmission is correct.

I cant find any other cases like this searching but there must be an error somewhere that either Laravel or more likely nginx is picking up some part of the header as part of the file stream when it begins counting the content-length.

Laravel 8, nginx 1.18, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

So far i've explored restructuring the response code but it doesnt seem to matter whether im using return response() or other wrapped responses they all respond the same.

all research cant find any matches on injected characters in file responses, im hoping the brains trust here has seen something like this before.

Comment: Update, in continuing to research this, in the hope of isolating the problem i came across a very old post that suggested some data was being left in the PHP output buffer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390607/white-spaces-send-in-my-file-when-downloading

the answer appears to be to call ob_clean() prior to returning a response-download in Laravel.  

Why this is the case I don't know.